# Setting up width for Jquery modal pop up div from code behind c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am calling `jQuery` Modal Pop up with some dynamic information, How I can set width of modal popup div from my c# Code.

Here is my current call from c#

```
string jqmsg = " Dear Applicant,</br> <p>Your enquiry registered, The Email verification link has been sent to you registred Email ID " + txtEmail.Text + " and your registration reference ID is <Strong> " + Session["REGID"].ToString() + " </Strong></p>";
                                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Popup", "ShowPopup('" + jqmsg + "');", true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add a parameter to the ShowPopup function that takes the width and then set the width in the ShowPopup javascript function?

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Popup", "ShowPopup('" + jqmsg + "'); width:400px;", true); this is what you mean? I tried not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would answer the comment I made above with an answer so I could more easily show code. This is what I mean:

**c#**

```
var width = 400;
string jqmsg = " Dear Applicant,</br> <p>Your enquiry registered, The Email verification link has been sent to you registred Email ID " + txtEmail.Text + " and your registration reference ID is <Strong> " + Session["REGID"].ToString() + " </Strong></p>";
                                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Popup", "ShowPopup('" + jqmsg + "', " + width + ");", true);
```

**javascript**

```
function ShowPopup(message, width) {
    // other ShowPopupCode
    document.getElementById("modalDivId").style.width = width + 'px';
}
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: Let me check and get back to you give me few minutes.

Comment: No buddy its still appearing same size.

Comment: @Vijay Kumbhoje , is your javascript function receiving the width value from your c# code? If it is can you please share the HTML for you modal and the javascript you're using for ShowPopup? A fiddle will do fine for that.

Comment: <div id="regMessage" style="display: none;">
        </div> this is my HTML Markup. is it this display none making problem?

Comment: display: none will make it so that the div will not show up at all, I would assume if this was the problem you would know about it. I need more to go on that this though. Please put together a fiddle of the javascript and HTML snippets that are failing and I'd be happy to assist. At the moment I don't have enough information to give you any meaningful advice.

*EDIT*: Also you didn't mention if the width value is being received by your javascript or not.

Comment: I set the default size in Javascript section it works but not exactly what I am expecting to resize the dialog size from c# Code.